# $E/K$ is finite Galois extension. Let $G(E/K)=\{\sigma_i\}$ be its Galois group. Then $\sigma_i$ are linearly independent over $E$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

$E/K$ is finite Galois extension. Let $G(E/K)=\{\sigma_i\}$ be its Galois group.

$\textbf{Q1}:$ Then $\sigma_i$ are linearly independent over $E$?(I do not want to use normal basis statement to deduce $E\otimes_KE\cong E[G]$ and this will assert linear independence over $E$). How do I see this directly?

$\textbf{Q2}:$ This is a step used in the proof of Hilbert 90 thm. However, I do not see I need cyclicness of the group for above question. Am I right on this?

Comment: linearly independent in what space? Per se, $\sigma_i\in\operatorname{Hom}_K(E,E)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Linearly independent as $E$ vector space in $<G(E/K)>_E\subset Hom_K(E,E)$.

Comment: Any set of automorphisms of a field $E$ is linearly independent over $E$: this is *Dedekind's Lemma*.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I was dumb. Thanks. So I do not even need cyclicity here.